# How to flatten a pandas DataFrameGroupBy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a `grouped` object which is of type `DataFrameGroupBy`. I want to use this to aggregate some data like so:

```py
aggregated = grouped.aggregate([np.sum, np.mean], axis=1)
```

This returns a `DataFrame` with the format:

```py
aggregated[:3].to_dict()
    """
    {('VALUE1', 'sum'): {
        ('US10adam034', 'PRCP'): 701,
        ('US10adam036', 'PRCP'): 1015,
        ('US10adam036', 'SNOW'): 46},
     ('VALUE1', 'mean'): {
        ('US10adam034', 'PRCP'): 100.14285714285714,
        ('US10adam036', 'PRCP'): 145.0,
        ('US10adam036', 'SNOW'): 46.0}}
    """
```

Printing out the head produces this:

```
                    VALUE1            
                       sum        mean
ID          ELEMENT                   
US10adam034 PRCP       701  100.142857
US10adam036 PRCP      1015  145.000000
            SNOW        46   46.000000
US10adam046 PRCP       790  131.666667
US10adam051 PRCP         5    0.555556
US10adam056 PRCP       540   31.764706
            SNOW        25    1.923077
            SNWD       165   15.000000
```

**This works great**. It easily computes *sums* and *means* for my sample where the grouped indices are `(ID, ELEMENT)`. However, I'd really like to get this into a **single row** format where *ID is unique* and the columns are a combination of `ELEMENT` & `(sum|mean)`. I can *almost* get there using `apply` like so:

```py
def getNewSeries(t):
    # type(t) => Series
    element = t.name[1] # t.name is a tuple ('ID', 'ELEMENT')
    sum_index=f'{element}sum'
    mean_index=f'{element}mean'
    return pd.Series(t['VALUE1'].values, index=[sum_index, mean_index])

aggregated.apply(getNewSeries, axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

Printing out the head again I get:

```
                       PRCPmean  PRCPsum   SNOWmean  SNOWsum  SNWDmean  ...
ID          ELEMENT                                                      
US10adam034 PRCP     100.142857    701.0        NaN      NaN       NaN   
US10adam036 PRCP     145.000000   1015.0        NaN      NaN       NaN   
            SNOW            NaN      NaN  46.000000     46.0       NaN   
US10adam046 PRCP     131.666667    790.0        NaN      NaN       NaN   
US10adam051 PRCP       0.555556      5.0        NaN      NaN       NaN   
US10adam056 PRCP      31.764706    540.0        NaN      NaN       NaN   
            SNOW            NaN      NaN   1.923077     25.0       NaN   
            SNWD            NaN      NaN        NaN      NaN      15.0
```

**I would like my final DataFrame to look like this:**

```
            PRCPmean    PRCPsum   SNOWmean  SNOWsum  SNWDmean  ...
ID                                                               
US10adam034 100.142857  701.0     NaN       NaN      NaN   
US10adam036 145.000000  1015.0    46.000000 46.0     NaN     
US10adam046 131.666667  790.0     NaN       NaN      NaN   
US10adam051 0.555556    5.0       NaN       NaN      NaN   
US10adam056 31.764706   540.0     1.923077  25.0     15.0
```

Is there a way, using `apply`, `agg` or `transform` to aggregate this data into single rows? I've tried also creating my own iterator over unique IDs but it was painfully slow. I like the ease of using `agg` to compute sum/mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like using f-string with list comprehensions.. Python 3.6+ required for f-string formatting.

```
df_out = df.unstack()['VALUE1']
df_out.columns = [f'{i}{j}' for i, j in df_out.columns]
df_out
```

Output:

```
             PRCPsum  SNOWsum    PRCPmean  SNOWmean
US10adam034    701.0      NaN  100.142857       NaN
US10adam036   1015.0     46.0  145.000000      46.0
```

Comment: Thank you Scott! Very fast solution. Processed ~65K rows in ~52ms.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
new_df = agg_df.unstack(level=1)
new_df.columns = [c+b for _,b,c in new_df.columns.values]
```

Output:

```
             PRCPsum  SNOWsum    PRCPmean  SNOWmean
US10adam034    701.0      NaN  100.142857       NaN
US10adam036   1015.0     46.0  145.000000      46.0
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
aggregated = grouped['VALUE1'].aggregate([np.sum, np.mean], axis=1)
aggregated=aggregated.unstack()
aggregated.columns=aggregated.columns.map('{0[1]}|{0[0]}'.format)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if reset_index is working as per your need

```
aggregated.apply(getNewSeries, axis=1, result_type='expand').reset_index()
```

Comment: I like this simple one-liner! However, it is very slow compared to other solutions using `unstack()` and list comprehension. One might only want to use `reset_index()` on small datasets.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try with [unstack()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) to move the innermost row index to become the innermost column index to reshape you data.

And you can also use fill_value to change NaNs to 0